# react onClick keycode got undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I know that with`keypress` or `keyDown` I can check which key is pressed, but with `onClick` I'm not able to do so.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  handleClick = e => {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
  };
  render() {
    return <h1 onClick={this.handleClick}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>;
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/ovwn9z6owz

What's the issue here?

Comment: The keyCode is a property of KeyboardEvent, not of ClickEvent therefore it is undefined...

Answer (score 4):

keycode is for `KeyboardEvent` not mouse clicks and anyway considered obsolete.
From the [Keyboard​Event​.key​Code
 MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode):

> This feature is no longer recommended. Though some browsers might
>   still support it, it may have already been removed from the relevant
>   web standards, may be in the process of being dropped, or may only be
>   kept for compatibility purposes. Avoid using it, and update existing
>   code if possible; see the compatibility table at the bottom of this
>   page to guide your decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to
>   work at any time.

Answer (score 3):

The `onClick` prop of react dispatches `React.ClickEvent` which doesn't have a `keyCode` property. Since it's a mouse event, the existence of keyboard related properties on the event object is illogical.

The keyboard related properties exist on `React.KeyboardEvent` which is dispatched by react's keyboard event related props such as `onChange`, `onKeyup`, `onKeyDown` etc

https://codesandbox.io/s/kkv9ol6pr7

Answer (score 0):

Hi here you're using  h1 tag, in this tag not possible to handle onClick function do it in Button  tag and then try it works.

and you need to send a parameter inside the onClick like `onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}`

```
<Button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>Hello CodeSandbox</Button>
```

for particular keyCode you go throug the below link

[Key Code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)